# Create associative array from numeric array and function?

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

I have a numeric array with codes like this: array('123', '333', '444');
I also have a function that given a code returns a name, so myFunc('123') would return 'soap'

I'd like to generate an associative array containing codes as keys and names as values. Is there any function that would allow me to do this? I know a foreach loop would do it but I wonder if there's some made function for this. Saw some methods like array_map but they don't seem to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_combine($arr, array_map('myFunc', $arr))
```

But two functions, not one ;-) Still oneliner though